# Apache2 restart failed

Tags: apache, restart, owncloud

I'm trying to install ownCloud on my Raspberry Pi. To install this I use this tutorial: http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=21870 (it's in german)

So I did everything like described and after the configtest I wanted to restart with

`apache2ctl restart`

I got this:

`httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.`

I found this information in the error log but I don't understand what the problem is:

```
[Mon Nov 03 09:17:46 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations [Mon Nov 03 09:17:59 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down 
[Mon Nov 03 09:18:01 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Mon Nov 03 09:18:46 2014] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName 
[Mon Nov 03 09:18:50 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Mon Nov 03 09:24:37 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Mon Nov 03 09:24:39 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 configured -- resuming normal operations [Mon Nov 03 09:32:51 2014] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart 
[Mon Nov 03 09:32:53 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) HP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:33 2014] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart 
[Mon Nov 03 09:36:35 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) HP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 configured -- resuming normal operations [Mon Nov 03 10:21:15 2014] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have something else using port 443.  Also, I believe the tutorial you mentioned is incorrect as you cannot bind an SSL VHost on a catchall IP (*:443 is not valid).

Change the vhost bind to read something like 192.168.1.60:443, where this is the static public IP of your Raspberry Pi.

Also, you should check what other services you are running on the system, and see if any of them is bound to run on port 443. You can do this by running the command `netstat -lntp`.